# iOS how to find the screen position of the side scroll bar in a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Is there a way to find the x and y position of the side scroll bar and track it as it moves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try taking the position of the scroll from the contentOffset property. But it doen't respond to scroll view delegates methods.